# (так как он (я сейчас вообще не шучу!) никогда-никогда меня в беде не оставит)

Tags: скобки

Лопатин говорит – http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=128#pp128, – что если уже какая-то часть заключена – на праве того, что является вторичной, – в скобки, то надо, если в этой фразе, в скобки заключённой, есть ещё мини вторичная фраза, использовать не скобки, а тире. Так же говорит да и Розенталь, однако. Правда тогда, что так, как пример, писать нельзя?

*Мой кот был очень хорошим (так как он (я сейчас вообще не шучу!) никогда-никогда меня в беде не оставит), а кот моего соседа – это был просто-таки демонище.*

И правдо ли, что надо бы так писать только?

*Мой кот был очень хорошим (так как он –я сейчас вообще не шучу! – никогда-никогда меня в беде не оставит), а кот моего соседа – это был просто-таки демонище.*

Comment: Тыквинский-Леопольдовский, скобки не оправданы, достаточно согласовать и не перегружать фразу, пример такой себе. Тем более, что проблема с временным соотнесением "был хорошим" и "не оставит". Это первое. Второе: "кот", в русском языке, это не понятие, это называние существа - кот. Понятие в русском звучит как "кошачье". И если сказать: моё кошачье было очень хорошим, - тут уже перебор с юмором.